# HTML send and receive data from another server

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, request

Failed trying to find "newest" solution to send data from client and receive the data with another server.
One solution I found is the "Google Analytics" way- send data with image request.
I have looked https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview, and have overall concepts. 
Question about this is how can I send image request and process the image request like

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com...
```

in another server? Example will help a lot.

Also I will be so happy if someone can share another way of doing it.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide an example of the kinds of data you want to send and receive.

Comment: For example I want to send information of browser name and browser version.

Comment: ok, firstly if you own the other server you should not be doing this. CORS call ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing you can set it so that you can make ajax calls. If not then, you can use an <img src="<paste you url here with get parameters that you want>"></img>. Image calls are not blocked across different domains.

Comment: that is true, but can you read further in the document you linked ? you might have to do a lot of things, you are not going to get a fixed URL.

Comment: @DarthCoder how would you process the image request in the server side (another server)? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: oh lets say you are www.google-analytics.com. to process the request, you need to write a controller that understands the URL.
what technology are you using on the server end. it varies based on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a request to the same domain, you can use root-relative paths instead of including the domain. example: GET `/path/to/action`

Otherwise you could use JSONP if the remote server supports it.

Comment: Yes I am looking for the solution with different domains. JSONP looks like getting the data 'from' different domains. But I want to send data to the different domain and read the data in the different domain.

Comment: You can still send data with JSONP, you just have to use query parameters (aka GET params) like
`"?callback=something&browser=chrome&version=36.0"`
Do you control both servers? Why are they on different domains?